# understanding logic flow Struts

Tags: html, jsp, struts

first off, i'm new to Struts and i have been following the tutorial [here](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html). I understand the set-up of files, and `web.xml`.

**index.jsp**:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<logic:redirect forward="helloWorld"/>
```

However, when it comes to the opening of `index.jsp`, i am at quite a loss. From `index.jsp`, how does it call the class `com.vaannila.action.HelloWorldAction`? I know that `index.jsp` calls the `forward=helloWorld` but does it mean that it looks for a `forward name="helloWorld"`, which is in `<global-forwards>`?

Let me know how I can further improve my question, since this is my first.

Comment: In terms of further improvement, I'd aim more at the ability to find and read the actual framework documentation: tutorials are an *adjunct* to framework docs, not a replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct; it redirects to whatever forward is named `"helloWorld"`.

In this case, that's a forward that runs an action that sticks a value into a form.

You'll likely want to refer to the [Struts 1 tag docs](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/index.html), it'll be quicker than asking here every time.

If you can avoid learning Struts 1, I would: it's pretty antiquated on almost all fronts. Frameworks like Struts 2 and Spring MVC dominate Java-framework-based web apps, while things like Grails, Play, Ruby on Rails, etc. dominate JVM-based web apps.

---

Line 17 of the config file in the tutorial you link to starts:

```xml
<action path="/helloWorld" 
        type="com.vaannila.action.HelloWorldAction" 
        name="helloWorldForm">
  <forward name="success" path="/helloWorld.jsp" />
</action>
```

Comment: so in the `<global-forwards>` tag, the path `helloWorld.do` is called...but i don't seem to see where `helloWorld.do` is mapped to the class `com.vaannila.action.HelloWorldAction` please advise, thanks

Comment: @gabybaby You don't? It's right there on line 17 in struts-config; added the config to my answer. This is why I think it will be important for you to read the actual Struts documentation.

Comment: also, i have no say in choosing Struts 1.0 as thats what my employer is using :\  Hopefully it will help me pick up 2.0 more easily in the future

Comment: @gabybaby That's not Struts 1.0 in the tutorial, that's Struts 1.3. If you truly need to use Struts 1.0, I'd *strongly* consider quitting immediately. Also, Struts 2 is a *completely* different framework, and nothing you learn in Struts 1 will be of any value whatsoever, IMO.

Comment: i do see and understand the `<action-mappings>` but i dont see the words `helloWorld.do` in the action-mappings..maybe i'm missing something? Unless somehow the `/` in the action-path is ignored to match the forward-name in `<global-forwards>`

Comment: @gabybaby You *are* missing something: reading the Struts 1 docs. The Struts 1 servlet is mapped to `*.do`. `*.do` is the default Struts 1 action mapping extension. The `*.do` is *not* reflected in the action mapping, so ignore that, and look at the part *before* the `.do`.

Comment: @gabybaby It's bad if the tutorial (1.3) and your app (1.1) diverge in functionality, because at this point I don't know as you'd be able to make the necessary adjustments.